# ErrorException; Line 2302

Tags: laravel-5.1

Good Day!

Please help me solve this problem. I am new to Laravel 5.1 and have already tried to google this ErrorException but I could not find any solution.

Here's my Controller code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //var_dump(json_decode($request->get('production_details'))); exit;
        $arr = json_decode($request->get('production_details'));
        for($a = 0; $a < sizeof($arr); $a++){
            $production_details = new MakeProduction(array(
                'prod_details_production_id'    => $request->get('production_id'),
                'prod_details_machine_id'       => $this->ExtractProductionDetails($arr[$a], 1),
                'prod_details_model_parts_id'   => $this->ExtractProductionDetails($arr[$a], 2)
            ));
            //$production_details->save();
        }
        return redirect('/makeproduction')
               ->with('status', 'Make Production was successfully added!');
    } 

 public function ExtractProductionDetails($json, $key){
        $arrs = get_object_vars($json);
        switch($key){
            case 1:
                return $arrs['machine_model_machine_id'];
            case 2:
                return $arrs['model_parts_id'];
        }

    }
```

Thank you for any help!

```html
int(1)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
        <style>
            /* Copyright (c) 2010, Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved. Code licensed under the BSD License: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/license.html */
            html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}legend{color:#000;}

            html { background: #eee; padding: 10px }
            img { border: 0; }
            #sf-resetcontent { width:970px; margin:0 auto; }
                        .sf-reset { font: 11px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; color: #333 }
            .sf-reset .clear { clear:both; height:0; font-size:0; line-height:0; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix:after { display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:inline-block; }
            .sf-reset * html .clear_fix { height:1%; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:block; }
            .sf-reset, .sf-reset .block { margin: auto }
            .sf-reset abbr { border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; cursor: help; }
            .sf-reset p { font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#868686; padding-bottom:20px }
            .sf-reset strong { font-weight:bold; }
            .sf-reset a { color:#6c6159; cursor: default; }
            .sf-reset a img { border:none; }
            .sf-reset a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
            .sf-reset em { font-style:italic; }
            .sf-reset h1, .sf-reset h2 { font: 20px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif }
            .sf-reset .exception_counter { background-color: #fff; color: #333; padding: 6px; float: left; margin-right: 10px; float: left; display: block; }
            .sf-reset .exception_title { margin-left: 3em; margin-bottom: 0.7em; display: block; }
            .sf-reset .exception_message { margin-left: 3em; display: block; }
            .sf-reset .traces li { font-size:12px; padding: 2px 4px; list-style-type:decimal; margin-left:20px; }
            .sf-reset .block { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:10px 28px; margin-bottom:20px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 16px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 16px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
                border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
                border-right:1px solid #ccc;
                border-left:1px solid #ccc;
            }
            .sf-reset .block_exception { background-color:#ddd; color: #333; padding:20px;
                -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 16px;
                -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 16px;
                -moz-border-radius-topleft: 16px;
                -moz-border-radius-topright: 16px;
                border-top-left-radius: 16px;
                border-top-right-radius: 16px;
                border-top:1px solid #ccc;
                border-right:1px solid #ccc;
                border-left:1px solid #ccc;
                overflow: hidden;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            .sf-reset a { background:none; color:#868686; text-decoration:none; }
            .sf-reset a:hover { background:none; color:#313131; text-decoration:underline; }
            .sf-reset ol { padding: 10px 0; }
            .sf-reset h1 { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding: 15px 28px; margin-bottom: 20px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
                -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
                    <div id="sf-resetcontent" class="sf-reset">
                <h1>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</h1>
                                        <h2 class="block_exception clear_fix">
                            <span class="exception_counter">1/1</span>
                            <span class="exception_title"><abbr title="ErrorException">ErrorException</abbr> in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php line 2302" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Model.php line 2302</a>:</span>
                            <span class="exception_message">in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given</span>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="block">
                            <ol class="traces list_exception">
       <li> in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php line 2302" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Model.php line 2302</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions">HandleExceptions</abbr>->handleError('2', 'in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given', 'C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php', '2302', <em>array</em>('key' => 'prod_details_production_id'))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>in_array('prod_details_production_id', 'prod_details_id') in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php line 2302" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Model.php line 2302</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model">Model</abbr>->isGuarded('prod_details_production_id') in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php line 2287" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Model.php line 2287</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model">Model</abbr>->isFillable('prod_details_production_id') in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php line 421" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Model.php line 421</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model">Model</abbr>->fill(<em>array</em>('prod_details_production_id' => '', 'prod_details_machine_id' => '1', 'prod_details_model_parts_id' => '40')) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php line 278" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Model.php line 278</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model">Model</abbr>->__construct(<em>array</em>('prod_details_production_id' => '', 'prod_details_machine_id' => '1', 'prod_details_model_parts_id' => '40')) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\app\Http\Controllers\Transactions\MakeProductionController.php line 44" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">MakeProductionController.php line 44</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Forecaster\Http\Controllers\Transactions\MakeProductionController">MakeProductionController</abbr>->store(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array(<em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Forecaster\Http\Controllers\Transactions\MakeProductionController">MakeProductionController</abbr>), 'store'), <em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php line 256" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Controller.php line 256</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Controller">Controller</abbr>->callAction('store', <em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php line 164" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ControllerDispatcher.php line 164</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher">ControllerDispatcher</abbr>->call(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Forecaster\Http\Controllers\Transactions\MakeProductionController">MakeProductionController</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>), 'store') in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php line 112" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ControllerDispatcher.php line 112</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher">ControllerDispatcher</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 139" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 139</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 103" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 103</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->then(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php line 114" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ControllerDispatcher.php line 114</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher">ControllerDispatcher</abbr>->callWithinStack(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Forecaster\Http\Controllers\Transactions\MakeProductionController">MakeProductionController</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), 'store') in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php line 69" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ControllerDispatcher.php line 69</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher">ControllerDispatcher</abbr>->dispatch(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), 'Forecaster\Http\Controllers\Transactions\MakeProductionController', 'store') in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php line 201" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Route.php line 201</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>->runWithCustomDispatcher(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php line 134" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Route.php line 134</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>->run(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php line 704" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Router.php line 704</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 139" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 139</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 103" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 103</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->then(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php line 706" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Router.php line 706</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->runRouteWithinStack(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php line 671" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Router.php line 671</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->dispatchToRoute(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php line 631" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Router.php line 631</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->dispatch(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php line 236" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Kernel.php line 236</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel">Kernel</abbr>->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 139" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 139</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken">VerifyCsrfToken</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array(<em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Forecaster\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken">VerifyCsrfToken</abbr>), 'handle'), <em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 124" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 124</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 54" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 54</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession">ShareErrorsFromSession</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array(<em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession">ShareErrorsFromSession</abbr>), 'handle'), <em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 124" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 124</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php line 62" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">StartSession.php line 62</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession">StartSession</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array(<em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession">StartSession</abbr>), 'handle'), <em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 124" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 124</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse">AddQueuedCookiesToResponse</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array(<em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse">AddQueuedCookiesToResponse</abbr>), 'handle'), <em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 124" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 124</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php line 59" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">EncryptCookies.php line 59</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies">EncryptCookies</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array(<em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Forecaster\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies">EncryptCookies</abbr>), 'handle'), <em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 124" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 124</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode">CheckForMaintenanceMode</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array(<em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode">CheckForMaintenanceMode</abbr>), 'handle'), <em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 124" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 124</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 103" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 103</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->then(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php line 122" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Kernel.php line 122</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel">Kernel</abbr>->sendRequestThroughRouter(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php line 87" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Kernel.php line 87</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel">Kernel</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\Apache24\htdocs\forecaster\public\index.php line 54" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">index.php line 54</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>

            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks to be an error in one of your Eloquent Models...

Comment: In your models, the `fillable` and/or `guarded` properties must be an array. Somewhere you have set one of those to be a string.

Comment: Thank you very much.. In my Model I have this 
before : protected $guarded = "prod_details_id";

Then changed to : protected $guarded = ["prod_details_id"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put my comment into an answer:

The error message means that in one of your Eloquent Model classes, you have either `fillable` or `guarded` properties set to a string instead of array. It should be set as follows:

```
class MyModel extends Model {

    protected $fillable = array('first_key', 'second_key');

}
```